# Bind Method With Delegate

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I'm creating a binding library to bind native Objective-C framework.

I have the following delegate  which I need to add it's declaration to ApiDefinition file and then I need to implement it using my Xamarin.iOS app:

```
- (void)Initialize:(id <MMSDKDelegate> _Nullable)pDelegate;
```

**MMSDKDelegate:**

```
@protocol MMSDKDelegate <IMMDelegate>
- (void)Started;
@end
```

**IMMDelegate:**

```
@protocol IMMDelegate
- (void)Inserted;
- (void)Removed;
- (void)ReaderConnected;
- (void)ReaderRemoved;
@end
```

I need the required definition in ApiDefinition file and I need a sample code to call this method from my Xamarin.iOS app.

**Update**

The Framework I'm dealing with is communicating with [card reader device](https://precisebiometrics.com/products/smart-card-reader/iphone/) attached with iPhone to read ID card info, it has methods to be called on reader inserted / removed & card inserted / removed..

I have implemented the answer by @cole-xia, but the issue is the methods inside `IMMDelegate` are never called when I insert card reader or ID. When I call `ReadCardData()`, it should call `Started()` which will display information saved by `Inserted()`, but the current result is that `Started()` method is called after calling `ReadCardData()`, but `Inserted()` and `ReaderConnected()` are never called in any stage.

In the demo app of Framework, it is used as the following (and works properly):

```
// Demo app -> ViewController.m

@interface ViewController () <MMSDKDelegate>

@end


@implementation ViewController {
    MMSDK *sdkInstance;
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    sdkInstance = [MMSDK SharedInstance];
    [sdkInstance Initialize:self];
}


- (void)Started
{
    // Update UI by: reading in progress ..
}


- (void)Inserted
{
    // Update UI by: card inserted
    // And read card data
    [self readData:self];
}

- (void)Removed
{
    // Update UI by: card removed
}

- (void)ReaderConnected
{
    // Update UI by: card reader connected
}

- (void)ReaderRemoved
{
    // Update UI by: card reader removed
}


- (IBAction)readData:(id)sender
{
    var *data = [sdkInstance ReadCardData:YES pWithSignatureImage:YES pWithAddressData:YES];
    if (data.hasError) {
        // No data fetched
        return;
    }

    if (data) {
        // return card data
    }
}
```

All suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

**In summary, I just need to do same functionality of demo app in Xamarin.iOS app.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[Sharpie](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries/#Binding_Protocols)** to create  `ApiDefinition`

The result on my side :

```
// @protocol IMMDelegate
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
[Protocol, Model]
interface IMMDelegate
{
    // @required -(void)Inserted;
    [Abstract]
    [Export ("Inserted")]
    void Inserted ();

    // @required -(void)Removed;
    [Abstract]
    [Export ("Removed")]
    void Removed ();
}

// @protocol MMSDKDelegate <IMMDelegate>
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
[Protocol, Model]
interface MMSDKDelegate : IMMDelegate
{
    // @required -(void)Started;
    [Abstract]
    [Export ("Started")]
    void Started ();
}

// @interface ACR : NSObject
[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
interface YourClass
{
    // -(void)Initialize:(id<MMSDKDelegate> _Nullable)pDelegate;
    [Export ("Initialize:")]
    void Initialize ([NullAllowed] MMSDKDelegate pDelegate);
}
```

### Usage:

```
class MyDelegate : MMSDKDelegate {
    public void Started()
    {
    }

    public override void Removed()
    {
    }
    public override void Inserted()
    {
    }
}


//In ViewController

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
    yourClass.Initialize(new MyDelegate());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please provide a sample on how `Initialize` method can be called from my ViewController?

Comment: Have you ever got a `Attempting to JIT compile method .. while running in aot-only` error?

Answer (score 1):

Along with Cola Xia's answer you may also need to make sure that, such third party device SDK integration requires some entries in the info.plist file's `"Supported external accessory protocols"` key.

Please check XCode sample and check if there is an entry for the `"Supported external accessory protocols"` key. If it is there, then you should add them in your Xamarin.iOS project's info.plist file.

I hope this may help!

Comment: I was not getting any error message saying that I have anything missing