# Framework doesn't detect card reader

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I have created binding library to bind a Framework supposed to read smart card data (it is working properly on XCode), but in Xamarin.iOS app, the card reader is never been detected.
I'm using [Tactivo card reader](https://precisebiometrics.com/products/smart-card-reader/).

**Note:** I tried all possible scenarios in the binding library and now I believe it is not an issue of binding library, there should be some libraries required to be loaded while application deployment to be able to let the Framework to be triggered by inserting the card reader. Or it is something related to permissions and app capabilities.

**App doesn't deal with the card reader at all!**

[Here you can find details about the binding library.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177710/bind-method-with-delegate)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the question it seems your app is successfully building and launching.

Such third party device integration requires some entries in the info.plist file's `"Supported external accessory protocols"` key.

Please check XCode sample and check if there is an entry for the `"Supported external accessory protocols"` key. If it is there, then you should add them in your Xamarin.iOS project's info.plist file.

I hope this may help!